# Compose AlertDialog not closing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a Dialog that I cant close when I press the button this is my code, I believe that is for the if cycle, but I need it to make it true under those circumstances, any idea that could help me here?

```
@Composable
    fun PopupWindowDialog(
    parentUiState: ParentHomeUiState,
) {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    if (!parentUiState.showInAppFeedback){
        openDialog.value = true
    }
    val recommend = sliderPosition.toInt()
    Column(
    ) {
        Box {
            if (openDialog.value) {
                Dialog(
                    onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value = false },
                    properties = DialogProperties(),
                ){
                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            //.padding(vertical = 70.dp, horizontal = 10.dp)
                            .padding(vertical = 70.dp )
                            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                            //.border(1.dp, color = Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                            .border(1.dp, color = Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                    ) {
                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(10.dp),
                            onClick = {
                              openDialog.value = !openDialog.value
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = "¡Contesta y gana +20 puntos!",
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a Dialog that I cant close when I press the button

Since you didn't show how your posted code (composable) is being called, ill assume the `.showInAppFeedback` is evaluating true.

Pay attention to these parts of your codes

```
val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

...
...

if (!parentUiState.showInAppFeedback) {
    openDialog.value = true
}
```

, `openDialog` is a state and when it changes value it will `re-compose` your entire composable, so when the dialog is visible, and when you set it to false via button click, the entire composable will re-compose and re-evaluate your if condition, setting openDialog.value to true again, and dialog will never close.

I don't know your use-case but you can wrap it inside a `LaunchedEffect`

```
LaunchedEffect(parentUiState.showInAppFeedback) {
    openDialog.value = true
}
```

Comment: yeah thats the thing, i dont know how to prevent it to enter the cycle again

Answer (score 1):

Since `parentUiState.showInAppFeedback` is not updated, `openDialog.value` will always be set to `true` when the view recomposes. You should use `parentUiState.showInAppFeedback` in the initial `remember` block but not for future recomposition.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PopupWindowDialog(parentUiState: ParentHomeUiState) {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(!parentUiState.showInAppFeedback) }
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val recommend = sliderPosition.toInt()
    Column {
        Box {
            if (openDialog.value) {
                Dialog(
                    onDismissRequest = { openDialog.value = false },
                    properties = DialogProperties(),
                ) {
                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            //.padding(vertical = 70.dp, horizontal = 10.dp)
                            .padding(vertical = 70.dp)
                            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                            //.border(1.dp, color = Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                            .border(1.dp, color = Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                    ) {
                        Button(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(10.dp),
                            onClick = {
                                openDialog.value = !openDialog.value
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = "¡Contesta y gana +20 puntos!",
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```